# How to query for an postgres integer array in spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am using Java 7 and JDBC template to query a integer array from PostgreSQL. My code is as below:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

String SQL = "select item_list from public.items where item_id=1";
List<Integer> ListOfitems=jdbcTemp.queryForList(SQL , Integer.class);
```

My `item_list` column is `integer[]` in PostgreSQL. But when I try like this it throws an error as:

> Bad value for type int psql exception

I also tried:

```
List<List<Integer>> ListOfitems=jdbcTemp.queryForList(SQL , Integer.class);
```

But it still throws the same exception.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/using-java-arrays-to-insert-retrieve-update-postgresql-arrays/

Comment: Thanks But I know how to retreive by prepared statement and connection.The issue I am facing here is to map to the correct class type when I use JDBC Termplate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of trial and error this made the trick.

```
List<Array>  ListOfitems=jdbcTemp.queryForList(SQL , java.sql.Array.class);
```

So basically the postgres array is equal to java sql array type.Hope it helps anyone :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [java.sql.Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).

If you want to get only integer array you can try like this (it works if result contains one row):

```
String SQL = "select item_list from public.items where item_id=1";
Array l = template.queryForObject(SQL, Array.class);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList((Integer[]) l.getArray());
```

Or use RowMapper

```
Foo foo = template.queryForObject(SQL, new RowMapper<Foo>(){
        @Override
        public Foo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            foo.setIntegers(Arrays.asList((Integer[]) rs.getArray("item_list").getArray()));
            return foo;
        }
    });
```

Class Foo:

```
class Foo {
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> integers;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the array field of the single row it should be something like:

```
import java.sql.Array;

...

final String sqlQuery = "...";
final Array itemListArray = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sqlQuery, Array.class);
```

Please note that the method call may throw the exception:

> `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` - if the query does not return exactly one row, or does not return exactly one column in that row
>
> — [JdbcTemplate (Spring Framework 4.3.10.RELEASE API) class, `public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: Just a quick question is itemListArray  Array  or List<Array>?

Comment: `Array` (`java.sql.Array`). Because it seems you would like to select the array field (`item_list`) of the single row found by its primary key (the `item_id` field).